# Meteor on android E chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)]

Tags: android, meteor, emulation, angular-meteor

Trying to do a very base build using meteor on android

get this as an output
App running at: http://localhost:3000/

```
=> Started app on Android Emulator.                                                                   
I20161017-16:55:12.315(-4)? 10-17 16:55:11.896  3884  3925 E chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)]
```

[GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7CFCD3A0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error
 from previous GL command

tried running meteor with crosswalk installed

```
=> Started app on Android Emulator.                                                                                                                             
I20161017-22:06:59.205(-4)? 10-17 22:06:57.568  2811  2811 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosit
y = 0                                                                                                                                                           
I20161017-22:06:59.267(-4)? 10-17 22:06:57.635  2811  2811 W chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()                               
I20161017-22:06:59.267(-4)? 10-17 22:06:57.828  2811  2811 D MeteorWebApp: Detected new bundled version, removing versions directory if it exists               
I20161017-22:06:59.267(-4)? 10-17 22:06:57.917  2811  2836 W chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup                  
I20161017-22:06:59.267(-4)? 10-17 22:06:58.220  2811  2811 I MeteorWebApp: Serving asset bundle with version: 8b6d25df1167033a4ee37d60879eebdc6d898b0c          
I20161017-22:06:59.268(-4)? 10-17 22:06:59.071  2811  2846 E chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7CE038A0]GL ERROR :GI20161017-22:07:00.954(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp: Download failure                                                                     
I20161017-22:07:00.954(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp: com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Skipping downloading new version because the Cordo
va platform version or plugin versions have changed and are potentially incompatible                                                                            
I20161017-22:07:00.954(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at com.meteor.webapp.WebAppLocalServer.shouldDownloadBundleForManifest(WebAppLoc
alServer.java:367)                                                                                                                                              
I20161017-22:07:00.954(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundleManager$1.onResponse(AssetBundleManager.java:131I20161017-22:07:00.955(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)                    
I20161017-22:07:00.955(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:111
3)                                                                                                                                                              
I20161017-22:07:00.955(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:58
8)                                                                                                                                                              
I20161017-22:07:00.955(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.848  2811  2875 E MeteorWebApp:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)                                        
I20161017-22:07:01.059(-4)? 10-17 22:07:00.955  2811  2811 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "Error: Skipping downloading new version because the Cordova platform 
version or plugin versions have changed and are potentially incompatible", source: http://localhost:12664/packages/webapp.js?hash=a09458059bd5dcc857ede183b8ac17
1c56a2e505 (64)
```

Comment: Do you even have a problem here - these lines are INFO and WARNING only - what is going wrong?

Comment: my mistake pasted the wrong code

Comment: Also posted on meteor forum
https://forums.meteor.com/t/e-chromium-error-buffer-manager-cc-340-groupmarkernotset-crbug-com-242999-7ce038a0-gl-error-g-l-invalid-operation-glbufferdata-error-from-previous-gl-command/30468?u=ajonp